# How to keep checkbox:checked persistent when tabbing in and out of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I've seen a couple questions similar to this one but am unsure on how to interpret the answers/if they are exactly relevant to my project.

I am building a site where there is a table of movie titles and associated checkboxes. I want the user to be able to check a box if they have seen the film and then be able to tab to a different page (within the same site), tab back, and still have the :checked boxes remain checked.

Is there a way to do this without a server-side language?

Here is the form section of the html if necessary:

https://gist.github.com/ripplep/1531daadc50f7f68e13a

Comment: It can be done using javascript by setting cookies or using 'Local Storage'. You just have to save the values in one place or the other. Then reload those values on page load. Both have drawbacks. Some people don't allow cookies so it won't work. With Local Storage you're storing the values in the browsers cache. So if a person uses a public computer, the next person that comes to your site on that computer will have the values set.

Comment: You really need to have a backend database with actual users registered and save the "viewed movies" as data somehow related to the user. This way, no matter what device the users use, their movies will be remembered. Local/session storage are not good solutions for this. [parse.com](http://parse.com) has an awesome Javascript API that would make such a system trivial to create.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. So I'm looking into parse.com. I'm watching tutorials on making blog posts, etc. Not quite seeing how I could save the data of checkboxes. Is there a faq or video with something close to what I want?